# Expressão regular para retornar texto entre chaves

Tags: python, regex

Eu tenho esta *String*:

```
str = "Eu sou uma string {dentro de uma string {dentro de outra} }"
```

Qual a expressão regular que eu posso usar para conseguir apenas:

```
dentro de uma string {dentro de outra}
```

Comment: Uma dica não relacionada com a pergunta: evite usar variáveis com nomes que sejam os mesmos que os tipos do Python. No caso "str" é igual ao da classe `str` do Python. Pode até parecer que "é um exemplo avulso, não atrapalha ninguém" - mas justo nesse caso, por exemplo, se alguém for copiar e colar a declaração acima para fazer testes no console do Python, vai sobre-escrever o "str" original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até é possível fazer uma regex que pegue o conteúdo que você precisa, mas há alguns poréns.

O primeiro é o que já foi mencionado nas outras respostas: regex não é a melhor ferramenta para resolver este problema. Não ficou claro se suas strings terão apenas dois pares de chaves aninhados, ou se a quantidade pode variar e não ter limite. Sendo assim, a verificação feita na [resposta do @jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354404/112052) é a solução mais indicada.

Os outros poréns são mencionados mais abaixo. De qualquer forma, deixo aqui - mais como curiosidade - uma solução com regex.

---

### Regex recursiva

Uma maneira de capturar o conteúdo entre pares de chaves, podendo ter outros pares aninhados, é usando uma [expressão regular recursiva](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html). No seu caso, poderia ser algo do tipo:

```
\{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)\}
```

`\{` e `\}` são os caracteres `{` e `}` propriamente ditos. Como estes caracteres possuem um significado especial em regex (servem para definir [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit)), eles precisam ser escapados com `\` para que "percam seus poderes" e sejam tratados apenas como caracteres "normais".

Depois temos um parênteses, que serve para definir um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), o que torna possível obter seu respectivo conteúdo posteriormente. Com isso, a expressão `\{(....)\}` significa que será possível obter posteriormente todo o conteúdo que está entre as chaves.

Logo em seguida temos `(?:`, que define um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Isso indica que estes parênteses estão sendo usados apenas para agrupar uma sub-expressão, e evita que a *engine* de regex crie um grupo de captura à toa. Dentro deste grupo de não-captura, temos uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (definida pelo `|`), o que significa que este grupo pode ter qualquer uma dentre estas duas coisas:

1. `[^{}]` - qualquer caractere que não seja `{` nem `}`, **ou**
2. `(?R)` - a própria expressão regular inteira, de forma recursiva

O primeiro caso (`[^{}]`) é uma [classe de caracteres negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). O início (`[^`) indica que eu não quero nenhum dos caracteres que aparecem em seguida. Como eu coloquei `{}`, quer dizer que eu não quero nem o `{`, nem o `}` - repare que dentro de colchetes esses caracteres não precisam ser escapados com `\`.

O segundo caso (`(?R)`) é a sintaxe para regex recursiva. Ela basicamente significa "pegue a regex inteira e coloque aqui no lugar do `(?R)`". Ou seja, a regex pode "estar dentro dela mesma", o que é uma forma de verificar pares de chaves dentro de outros pares de chaves.

Em seguida temos o quantificador `*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências" do que está antes (ou seja, do grupo de não-captura). Isso quer dizer que podemos ter vários caracteres que não sejam `{` nem `}`, **ou** a mesma regex (que é `{`, seguido de vários caracteres que não sejam `{` nem `}`, **ou** a mesma regex etc...), tudo isso repetido várias vezes, e cada uma dessas ocorrências tem um `}` ao final:

[image: explicação da regex recursiva]

Graças à recursão, a regex pode ter uma quantidade ilimitada de pares de chaves aninhados - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/GEzqbR/3) um exemplo dela funcionando.

**Infelizmente**, o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) - que é o módulo nativo do Python para trabalhar com expressões regulares - não suporta regex recursiva. Por isso este código não funciona:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'\{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)\}')
```

Ao tentar criar a regex recursiva, ocorre um erro:

> re.error: unknown extension ?R at position 13

---

### Então como eu faço?

Felizmente, no PyPI existe o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), que estende as funcionalidades do módulo `re` e possui suporte à regex recursiva:

```
import regex

r = regex.compile(r'\{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)\}')
print(r.findall("Eu sou uma string {dentro de uma string {dentro de outra} }"))
```

O módulo `regex` possui compatibilidade com o módulo `re`, então seus métodos se comportam da mesma maneira. O método [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), por exemplo, retorna uma lista com todas as strings que deram *match*, mas quando há grupos de captura, ele retorna uma lista com os grupos (este é mais um motivo para usar o grupo de não-captura internamente: para que ele não seja retornado por `findall`). Por isso este código imprime:

```
['dentro de uma string {dentro de outra} ']
```

Testando a mesma regex para outras strings:

```
print(r.findall('String {com {vários {níveis {de } chaves}} aninhadas}.'))
print(r.findall('Apenas {um par de} chaves'))
print(r.findall('String {com mais {de} um} trecho {com {chaves}}'))
```

Saída:

```
['com {vários {níveis {de } chaves}} aninhadas']
['um par de']
['com mais {de} um', 'com {chaves}']
```

Repare que a última possui mais de um trecho possível de ser capturado, por isso a lista retornada possui duas strings.

---

Há mais dois poréns nesta solução.

O primeiro é que esta regex também captura `{}`. Ou seja, este código:

```
print(r.findall('Chaves {} vazias'))
```

Retorna uma lista com uma string vazia:

```
['']
```

Isso acontece porque usei `*`, que significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências". Se eu quiser que tenha pelo menos um caractere dentro das chaves, basta mudar para `+`, que significa "**uma** ou mais ocorrências" ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/rn0MnA/2) a diferença):

```
import regex

r = regex.compile(r'\{((?:[^{}]|(?R))+)\}')
                                     ^
                usando + no lugar de *
```

Com isso, `findall` passa a ignorar os trechos que não possuem nenhum caractere entre as chaves (ignorando as ocorrências de `{}`), retornando uma lista vazia:

```
print(r.findall('Chaves {} vazias'))
```

Saída:

```
[]
```

Repare que agora a saída é uma **lista vazia** (nenhum grupo foi encontrado) em vez de uma **lista com um elemento** (foi encontrado um grupo, que é uma string vazia). Para as demais strings acima, o retorno continua sendo o mesmo.

---

O outro porém é que esta regex não verifica se as chaves estão balanceadas. Por exemplo, para a string `String com {chaves {desbalanceadas}`, o trecho capturado será apenas `desbalanceadas`, pois é o trecho que está dentro de um par de chaves balanceado (o trecho `{chaves` possui `{`, mas não possui o `}` correspondente e por isso fica de fora). Exemplo:

```
print(r.findall('String com {chaves {desbalanceadas}'))
print(r.findall('outro exemplo com {chaves} desbalanceadas}'))
print(r.findall('Somente abre { chaves.'))
```

Saída:

```
['desbalanceadas']
['chaves']
[]
```

Repare que na segunda string o trecho capturado foi `chaves`, pois é o que está dentro de um par de chaves balanceado (o trecho `desbalanceadas}` só possui a chave de fechamento, e por isso ficou de fora). Já a terceira string não possui `}`, então nenhum trecho é capturado (por isso o retorno é uma lista vazia).

Talvez seja até possível obter `chaves {desbalanceadas` no primeiro caso e `chaves} desbalanceadas` no segundo, mas aí a regex começa a ficar complicada demais. E de todo modo, já vimos nas outras respostas que [a solução ideal não usa regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354404/112052) e é de fato mais simples, não só de fazer e entender, mas também de modificar (por exemplo, para obter as posições de cada `{` e seu respectivo `}`, etc). Regex é uma ferramenta poderosa e muito legal (eu particularmente gosto muito), mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 4):

Apesar de provavelmente ser possível fazer isso com expressões regulares, talvez não seja a melhor forma de fazer isso - 
Expressões regulares são uma linguagem a parte da linguagem "hospede" - e são realmente "hostis" a quem estiver verificando o código. São muito úteis em alguns casos, e a medida que você se habitua, ou se exercita com elas, passam a valer a pena em cenários com complexidade crescente - já que, você, estando familiar, vai poder escrever a expressão regular mais rapidamente do que escreveria código equivalente na própria linguagem (nesse caso, Python).

Nesse caso, a expressão regular para isso teria que contar com match de grupos, contar grupos para trás, de forma opcional  - e, na verdade, talvez não seja possível escrever algum mecanismo equivalente a "recursão" para ignorar um número variável de `}`, se houverem várias aninhadas. Para um número máximo fixo de sub-chaves, acredito que seja possível sim - e talvez eu faça uma tentativa em breve.

No entanto, o que escrevi até aqui é pra dizer que **as vezes, programando na linguagem mesmo, algumas tarefas são ordens de grandeza mais simples do que usando expressões regulares**.

E isso parece ser o caso aqui. Afinal, tudo o que é preciso é manter uma variável que vai contar quantas chaves estão abertas, enquanto a string é percorrida caractere a caractere - quando o contador chegar em "0", você tem um trecho entre chaves no nível mais alto. Em Python são poucas linhas:

```
def find_bracket_groups(text):
    open_brackets = 0
    groups = []
    current_group = ""
    for char in text:
        if char == "{":
            open_brackets += 1
        if open_brackets > 0:
            current_group += char
        if char == "}":
            open_brackets -= 1
            if open_brackets == 0:
                groups.append(current_group)
                current_group = ""
            if open_brackets < 0:
                open_brackets = 0
    return groups
```

Apesar de parecer uma função grande, a leitura é trivial - e um pouco do tamanho é algum cuidado com casos especiais, por exemplo, tratar caracteres "}" que possam estar avulsos no texto.

Perceba também que se fosse necessário seria fácil alterar essa função para receber mais parâmetros, e poder localizar grupos mais "profundos" em vez de apenas o primeiro, ou achar grupos com outros caracteres diferentes de "{}". 
(Em contraste, parametrizar uma expressão regular iria exigir que a expressão regular fosse escrita como uma string que seria formatada com o método ".format" antes de ser usada como expressão regular - deixando o código ainda de leitura mais complicada).

**outra forma**

Se você sempre tiver um único grupo de "{...} " na raiz do texto, como no exemplo - isso é, nada do tipo "aaaaa { ocorrencia 1 {bbbb}} cccc { ocorrencia2}", é possível um código trivial em Python, que apenas "recorte" a string no primeiro caractere "{" e no último caractere "}" - com os métodos `.split` e `rsplit` dos objetos string:

```
text = "Eu sou uma string {dentro de uma string {dentro de outra} }"
result = text.split("{", 1)[-1].rsplit("}", 1)[0]
```

A expressão na última linha diz "corte a string em substrings separadas pelo caractere "}", começando da esquerda, apenas uma vez. Tome a última parte dessa divisão (descartando a primeira), e recorte no caractere "}" a partir da direita, uma única vez, e tome a primeira parte dessa divisão.

E note que essa expressão não verifica se de fato existe *qualquer* chave na string, então ela teria que ser complementada com um `if "{" in text: ...` em algum ponto para seu código ser robusto.

**update**

Como comentei acima - tentei criar uma expressão regular usando o padrão `(?(<grupo>)\})`  para dar um match em um "}" interno apenas se outro "{" interno foi visto (na documentação procure por ["yes-pattern|no-pattern"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)), mas realmente não é trivial - e fica bem difícil acompanhar (não chegou a funcionar). Para um número arbitrário de chaves aninhadas, só criando uma regexp "frankenstein" com um número máximo de grupos de `{`, cada um com o respectivo grupo "yes-pattern"  para o `}` correspondente - não seria prático.

Comment: se eu quiser, por exemplo, identificar como as chaves estão relacionadas. Por exemplo eu tenho a expressão `"a{ b{ c } d{ e } }"`, se eu quiser apenas as chaves, eu terei: `{{}{}}`, mas como posso identificar qual chave abre e qual fecha determinada expressão?

Comment: o código acima é um programa - você tem a faca, o queijo, na mão, e pode criar quantas variáveis quiser pra guardar a posição do que que quiser: os molhos, maionese, mostarda, e acompanhamentos.  E não, ele não volta só a estrutura de chaves - ele volta o que tem dentro do grupo de fora em uma estrutura de chaves. 
No caso, a função não retorna a posição de cada grupo de chaves, mas basta usar a função `enumerate` no `for` para ter a posição - com mais um if inserido depois da segunda linha dentro do `for`, pode anotar a posição de cada grupo se quiser.

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/regex-and-find)

Para esse problema específico, você não precisa de expressão regular, você pode usar `find` para construir um *slice*, veja:

```
print(str[str.find("{")+1:str.find(" }")])
dentro de uma string {dentro de outra}
```

Mas se você faz questão de usar expressões regulares, faça:

```
print(re.compile( "{(.*?) }").search(str).group(1))
dentro de uma string {dentro de outra}
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/regex-and-find)

> Editada:
>   Atendendo aos comentários do @jsbueno, vou reforçar o que coloquei logo no início (antes de quaisquer edições) da resposta: "Para esse problema específico", isto é, as soluções apresentadas aqui só servem para strings que tenham o mesmo formato da string originalmente apresentada na pergunta: ("Eu sou uma string {dentro de uma string {dentro de outra} }") (Em particular, dependem do *espaço em branco* antes da última chave - jsbueno). Aproveito também para corroborar o comentário do jsbueno na pergunta, a respeito do fato de se utilizar palavras reservadas para nomear variáveis.

Comment: essa regexp não é a resposta e você sabe disso - está funcionando com o exemplo por que tem um espaço antes da "}" de fora. O engine de regexp não oferece controle para o "match" de parentes/colchetes/chaves - sem esse espaço ele vai dar match na chave interna

Comment: (Agora uma dica, sem ser o erro: não precisa usar "re.compile" a não ser que você vá fazer   um cache manual de expressões regulares compiladas - pode usar direto `re.find(REGEXP, target)`  )

Comment: A primeira forma, com "find" também não vai funcionar como está se você remover o " " antes da chave - mas combinando "find" com ".rfind" sim, é possível achar o grupo mais de fora, se cada string tiver apenas _um_ grupo mais externo entre chaves.

Comment: @jsbueno Veja que eu fiz questão de colocar na resposta  (sem edição) "para esse problema especifico". :-)

Comment: bom - você sabe que está errado. a dúvida é conseguir as chaves aninhadas - e qualquer um pode ver isso, não achar uma forma que as chaves de fora NESSA string sejam distintas das chaves de dentro. De qualquer forma, os mecanismos da plataforma estão aí: vocẽ responde como quiser, eu voto como quiser.

Comment: Agora essa resposta incorreta pode confundir - não só o autor da questão, como outras pessoas no futuro com problemas semelhantes. Aí, só o downvote já não dá conta de remediar. fica a seu critério manter.

Comment: Ok, @jsbueno no stress. A resposta cria um exemplo completo e verificavel exatamente com a string colocada na pergunta, desculpe, mas vou mante-la.  Prospero 19, sinceramente.

Comment: se vocẽ só escrever no texto que essas soluções dependem do espaço eu já fico bem mais tranquilo! :-)

Comment: @jsbueno editei a resposta e acrescentei a observação, veja se ficou bom.

Comment: No final acho que foi muito mais util manter a reposta do que remove-la, até pelos comentários que podem suscitar curiosidades e vontades de aprender. :-)

Comment: eu só fazia questão mesmo de mencioanar que ela dependia do espaço -- acabei colocando na sua nota. Espero que esteja ok.