# Como remover todo o texto dentro de um parênteses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou querendo remover todo o texto dentro de um parênteses, junto com os parênteses, para retornar somente o texto que está fora deles, da seguinte forma:

```
texto = 'bla bla bla (ble ble)'
```

Quero que vire:

```
texto = 'bla bla bla'
```

Preciso alterar diversas células em um *dataframe* que possuem esse formato, se possível em Python.

Comment: E se tiver parenteses dentro de parenteses, `'bla (ble (bli))'`, deve remover tudo igual?

Comment: Acho que dá para adaptar [este algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354404/112052) (trocando as chaves por parênteses e removendo o trecho em questão em vez de guardá-lo)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
texto.replace(texto[texto.find("("):texto.find(")")+1], '').strip()
```

Que retornará:

```
'bla bla bla'
```

Comment: Aqui a saída do seu código foi `'a bla bla'`: https://ideone.com/YV8MUE

Comment: E se os parenteses estiverem no meio do texto ele não remove: https://ideone.com/h5Lhx3

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Corrigido. Obrigado por avisar!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na pergunta não diz nada sobre parênteses dentro de parênteses.

Comment: Não, por isso que eu perguntei para o autor.

Comment: Há muitas situações que são passíveis de acontecer que não estão listadas na pergunta. Parenteses dentro de parenteses é uma, outra seria ter parenteses incompletos, como em `'1) Olá mundo (ble)'`. Conforme descrito, a saída deveria ser `'1) Olá mundo'`. Ainda tem o caso de existirem múltiplos parenteses, como em `'uma (string) (qualquer)'`.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer gerar um novo texto que contenha todos os caracteres do texto original, exceto aqueles cercados por parênteses. Em outras palavras, você quer medir a profundidade de cada trecho do texto original e descartar os trechos cuja profundidade seja maior do que zero. (Por "profundidade" eu me refiro à quantidade de parênteses cercando um determinado trecho). Você resolve isso com um contador e um laço `for`.

O seguinte é um pseudocódigo procedural para o que acabei de descrever.

```
declare o contador de profundidade, inicialmente zerado
declare o novo texto, inicialmente vazio

para cada caractere C do texto original:
    se C for o caractere de abertura:
        incremente  o contador de profundidade
    senão:
        se C for o caractere de fechamento:
            decremente o contador de profundidade
        senão:
            Se o contador de profundidade estiver zerado:
                Adicione C ao novo texto
```

É fácil transcrever para a sintaxe do Python.

```py
def ignorar_caracteres_cercados(texto, char_abertura, char_fechamento):
    profundidade = 0
    novo_texto = ''

    for c in texto:
        if c == char_abertura:
            profundidade += 1
        elif c == char_fechamento:
            profundidade -= 1
            if profundidade < 0:
                raise Exception('Cercamento não balanceado')
        elif profundidade == 0:
            novo_texto += c

    if profundidade > 0:
        raise Exception('Cercamento não balanceado')

    return novo_texto
```

Note que eu tomei a liberdade de adicionar exceptions para o caso de os caracteres estarem desbalanceados. Você pode remover ou alterar isso conforme a sua necessidade.

Exemplo de uso:

```py
texto = 'hue bla bla bla (ble ble)x(bla (bla) bla) hue (((xoxoxo))) hue ()(a)()'
print(texto)
novo_texto = ignorar_caracteres_cercados(texto, '(', ')')
print(novo_texto)
```