# Retornar texto entre chaves, sem retornar as próprias chaves

Tags: java, regex

Usei a seguinte expressão regular em java para retornar strings que estão entre chaves:

```
\\{[^\\}]+?\\}
```

Meu Programa funcionou quase corretamente, porém ele retorna inclusive a chave.

**Algoritmo:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String data = "{Papel A}{Papel B}{} não é papapel";
        List<String> papeis = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{[^\\}]+?\\}");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(data);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String result = matcher.group();
            papeis.add(result);
        }

        for (String string : papeis) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

**Retorno:**

```
{Papel A}
{Papel B}
```

Gostaria de remover as chaves dos resultados que houverem match.

Acredito que que dê para resolver isso via regex, sem a necessidade de usar o método replace da classe `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução é colocar o trecho que você quer entre parênteses, pois isso formará um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Em seguida, basta passar o número do grupo para o método `group`:

```
String data = "{Papel A}{Papel B}{} não é papapel";
List<String> papeis = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^\\}]+?)\\}"); // coloquei o trecho que quero entre parênteses
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String result = matcher.group(1); // pego o primeiro grupo de captura
    papeis.add(result);
}
for (String string : papeis) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Repare que só deixei as chaves de fora dos parênteses, assim eles pegarão somente o conteúdo que está dentro delas. E como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, eles correspondem ao grupo 1, por isso eu faço `matcher.group(1)` para pegá-lo.

A saída é:

```
Papel A
Papel B
```

---

Lembrando que esta regex funciona desde que não haja um par de chaves dentro de outro. Se você tiver, por exemplo, `{abc{xxx}aaa}`, a regex pegará `abc{xxx`, pois ela vai avançando até encontrar o primeiro `}`. Você poderia alterá-la para `Pattern.compile("\\{([^{}]+)\\}")`, para que ela pegue somente o `xxx`, por exemplo.

Mas construir uma regex que detecte os casos de chaves aninhadas e pegue (usando o exemplo acima) `abc{xxx}aaa` é um pouco mais complicado, pois exige o uso de [regex recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354598/112052), que o Java não suporta.

Neste caso, a alternativa seria percorrer a string e ir contando as chaves manualmente (veja uma versão deste algoritmo [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354404/112052)):

```
String data = "{Papel A}{Papel B}{abc{xxx}aaa} não é papapel";
List<String> papeis = new ArrayList<String>();
int chave = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : data.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '{') {
        chave++;
    }
    if (chave > 0) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    if (c == '}') {
        chave--;
        if (chave == 0) {
            papeis.add(sb.toString().replaceAll("\\{(.+)\\}", "$1"));
            sb.setLength(0);
        }
        if (chave < 0) {
            chave = 0;
        }
    }
}
for (String string : papeis) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esse resolva seu problema

```
(?<=\{).+?(?=\})
```

Teste:
http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5d12729475622d756b0a0000

Answer (score -1):

Isto pode te ajudar

```
String suastringtratada = Normalizer.normalize(suastring, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

Comment: A pergunta pede para retornar uma string sem as chaves (`{abc}` deve resultar em `abc`), mas o código apresentado não faz isso ([veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/6qOZK8)). Na verdade o que esse código faz é remover os acentos (por exemplo, `{áéí}` se torna `{aei}`, [veja que só remove os acentos](https://ideone.com/HmjuyZ), mas não as chaves), e não vejo como isso pode estar relacionado com o problema apresentado na pergunta. Se puder [edit] a resposta explicando melhor...