# Remover caracteres de uma String (ou gerar uma nova sem eles) que estejam entre dois caracteres especiais

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Preciso de uma ajuda neste caso, tenho uma string e precisaria remover dela alguns caracteres.

```
String minhaStr = "{"abcde{"fg":"hij"}"
```

Preciso remover tudo o que está entre as chaves {, ou seja neste caso seria "abcde:

```
String minhaNovaStr = "{{"fg":"hij"}"
```

Não gostaria de utilizar substring ou algo do gênero pois na verdade tenho uma lista de strings que precisaria aplicar essa lógica, e elas não seguem o mesmo padrão de quantidade de caracteres por exemplo. O único padrão que elas seguem é que estão entre duas chaves {. Dei uma procurada sobre StringBuilder mas até o momento em minha pesquisa não encontrei nada em específico que possa me ajudar, alguém teria uma ideia por gentileza?

Comment: Não chega a ser exatamente igual, mas pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/393375/112052  - aproveitando, essas strings estão erradas e esse código não compila, por causa das várias aspas...