# Como pegar um valor entre muitas chaves, porém ignorando as chaves, exceto a mais interna?

Tags: regex

Estou tentando pegar o valor que está dentro das chaves. Exemplo:

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{Valor aqui dentro}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Estou fazendo os testes no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/23sVIZ/3). Queria que o resultado final fosse assim:

```
{Valor aqui dentro}
```

Eu já tentei desse modo:

```
\{.*\}
```

Mas seleciona o texto inteiro.

Comment: O que tem de errado nessa pergunta??

Comment: qual linguagem?

Comment: Não é linguagem, é para o meu tcc

Comment: Não estou usando linguageeem

Comment: Ok. Pq a aplicação do comando para retirar a string desejada depende da linguagem utilizada. Saberia responder se fosse no python, mas creio que, por exemplo, em JS a sintaxe é diferente

Comment: Ok, é que eu estou fazendo os testes no Regex 101, é por lá que estou testando

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro acho que vale explicar porque sua regex não funcionou.

Por padrão, os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (como `*` e `+`) são ["gananciosos" (*greedy*)](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres.

No seu caso, a regex é `\{.*\}`, ou seja: o caractere `{` seguido de zero ou mais caracteres (`.*`), seguido de `}`. O ponto corresponde a [qualquer caractere (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). E por "qualquer caractere", entenda que é qualquer um mesmo, inclusive `{` e `}` (se a regex julgar que é necessário para satisfazer a expressão, o ponto pode sim pegar esses caracteres).

Então no seu caso, os critérios da regex são: tem um `{`, seguido de vários caracteres (quaisquer um, inclusive outros `{` e `}`, se a regex achar necessário), seguido de um `}`. E qual a maior sequência de caracteres que corresponde a esses critérios? A string inteira. O trecho `\{` da regex pega o primeiro caractere `{`, o `.*` pega todos os outros dezenove `{`, mais o texto, mais os dezenove `}`, e por fim o `\}` pega o último `}` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/YO88cP/1/)).

---

Uma alternativa para resolver já foi dada na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/429351/112052): usar um quantificador ["preguiçoso" (*lazy*)](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution), ou seja, trocar `.*` por `.*?`. Isso faz com que a regex pegue a menor quantidade possível de caracteres, e com isso ela não pega mais `{` e `}` do que devia (para saber mais sobre quantificadores *lazy*, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052)).

Mas também dá para resolver de outras maneiras. Todo o problema começou porque você usou o ponto, que corresponde a qualquer caractere (qualquer um, inclusive os próprios `{` e `}`). Mas você não quer "qualquer caractere", e sim "qualquer um que **não** seja `{` ou `}`". Sendo assim, você pode usar esta regex:

```
^\{+(\{[^{}]+\})\}+$
```

Em vez do ponto, usei `[^{}]`, que é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Ela pega qualquer caractere que **não** seja o que está entre `[^` e `]` (no caso, é qualquer caractere que não seja `{` nem `}`). Outro detalhe é que troquei o `*` por `+`. Isso porque o `*` significa "**zero** ou mais caracteres", ou seja, se o texto for `{{{}}}`, a regex encontra o trecho `{}`. Já o `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", por isso ao trocar o `*` por `+`, eu garanto que deve ter pelo menos um caractere entre as chaves.

Com isso eu não preciso mais do quantificador *lazy*, pois agora não há o risco de pegar caracteres a mais - a classe de caracteres negados garante que a regex vai parar assim que encontrar o primeiro `{` ou `}`, o que não ocorria com o ponto. Isso traz uma *pequena* vantagem, pois a regex fica mais rápida - compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/uQ3zvM/2) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/JnGO7T/4) e veja que a quantidade de passos diminui mais que a metade (**obviamente**, para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença de desempenho será irrelevante - e admito que na maioria dos casos não passa de [micro-otimização](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471000) - mas dependendo do tamanho e natureza dos textos e da regex usada, o uso indiscriminado de `.*` [pode levar a resultados catastróficos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)). De qualquer forma, ainda existe outro fator importante, que é deixar mais clara a sua intenção: ao usar `.*` você dá a entender que qualquer coisa serve naquele trecho, já ao [ser mais específico](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) com `[^{}]`, você deixa bem claro que não é bem qualquer coisa que pode ter ali.

Por fim, usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que marcam respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que a string só tem o que está especificado na regex, nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos.

---

Já que falamos em ser mais específico, você pode ficar mudando a regex para que tenha exatamente o que você precisa. Usar `[^{}]` é um pouco melhor que `.`, pois restringe a lista de caracteres possíveis. Mas `[^{}]` ainda aceita muitas coisas que talvez você não queira, como caracteres especiais, quebras de linha, emojis, etc. **Se** você quiser restringir ainda mais, poderia usar outras opções. Exemplos:

- `[a-zA-Z ]` - aceita letras de A a Z (maiúsculas e minúsculas) e espaços (repare que há um espaço antes do `]`). Mas isso não aceita letras acentuadas, então...
- `[\w ]` - o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` considera letras, números e o caractere `_`. E se você ativar a *flag* unicode (no regex101, clique na bandeira que fica ao lado direito da regex e escolha a opção `u`), ele passa a considerar também caracteres acentuados.
- mas se não quiser números e nem o caractere `_`, pode usar `[\p{L} ]`: o atalho `p{L}` considera todas as letras definidas pelo Unicode (inclusive de outros alfabetos, como o grego, japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc)

Enfim, há muitas possibilidades, e tudo vai depender do que você precisa. Seu texto só tem letras do alfabeto latino e sem acentos? Também vai ter números, sinais de pontuação, etc? Ou você quer simplesmente qualquer coisa que esteja entre as chaves? Dependendo da ferramenta que você usa, pode ser também que alguma regex não funcione (o JavaScript, por exemplo, [não suporta o atalho `\p{L}` em todos os *browsers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes#Browser_compatibility), mas você poderia usar `[^\W\d_]`, que tem um funcionamento similar).

---

#### Chaves balanceadas

Não ficou claro se a expressão deve estar balanceada (ou seja, se cada `{` tem um `}` correspondente). De qualquer forma, abaixo estão algumas opções com regex (embora esta **não** seja a melhor ferramenta para verificar esse tipo de coisa - na verdade acho que nem é a melhor solução para o problema original, de pegar o texto entre as chaves, já que um *loop* simples pela string já resolveria).

Primeiro o caso mais simples. **Se** a quantidade de chaves é sempre a mesma, você pode simplesmente fazer algo do tipo:

```
^\{{19}(\{[^{}]+\})\}{19}$
```

No caso, `\{{19}` significa "exatamente 19 ocorrências do caractere `{`", e fiz o mesmo para o `\}`. Assim, eu garanto que a quantidade de `{` e `}` é a mesma ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/OwfzrV/2) a regex funcionando).

Agora, se a quantidade de chaves pode variar, aí é mais complicado. A solução ideal é não usar regex, e em vez disso, usar uma linguagem de programação para implementar algum algoritmo [similar a este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354404/112052).

Mas só como curiosidade, é possível verificar isso com [regex recursivas](http://rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html):

```
^(?=(\{([^{}]+|(?1))\})$)\{+(\{[^{}]+\})\}+$
```

O segredo está no trecho `(\{((?1)|[^{}]+)\})`. Primeiro a expressão está entre parênteses, formando um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - e como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o grupo 1.

Depois temos uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|` significa **ou**), com duas possibilidades:

- `[^{}]+` - qualquer caractere que não sejam as chaves, **ou**
- `(?1)`- que é "a mesma expressão que corresponde ao grupo 1" (a mesma regex é chamada aqui, de maneira recursiva)

Ou seja, este trecho pode ser interpretado como:

- o caractere `{`, seguido de:

  - qualquer caractere que não sejam as chaves, **ou**

    - o caractere `{`, seguido de:
    - qualquer caractere que não sejam as chaves, **ou**

      - o caractere `{`, seguido de:
      - qualquer caractere que não sejam as chaves, **ou**

        - ...
      - o caractere `}`
    - o caractere `}`
  - o caractere `}`

Com isso, a regex verifica se as chaves estão balanceadas. Além disso, todo o trecho está em um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (entre `(?=` e `)`), que serve para verificar se algo existe à frente (mas esse algo não faz parte do *match*, e fiz assim porque na regex recursiva não foi possível capturar o último trecho entre chaves diretamente). Logo depois do *lookahead* temos a regex que já vimos acima, para pegar o trecho desejado.

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/JnGO7T/10) esta regex funcionando, e repare que ela só pega casos em que as chaves estão balanceadas. A diferença para as soluções anteriores é que agora o trecho que você quer está no grupo 3, e não mais no grupo 1.

Mas como eu já disse, eu vejo isso mais como uma curiosidade do que de fato uma solução prática. Primeiro porque é uma solução complicada demais para algo que pode ser resolvido com um algoritmo simples, e segundo porque nem todas as linguagens suportam regex recursivas (o que pode ser considerado um ponto positivo, pois aí você nem cogita usá-las). Regex é legal e eu particularmente gosto bastante, mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: Nossa, que show! Até aprendi para que a flag `/u` funcionava. Como sempre, outra excelente resposta. :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe Só lembrando que o que eu disse sobre a flag `u` vale para o regex101. Em cada linguagem pode ter diferenças. Por exemplo, no Python 3 o modo Unicode é o *default* e nem precisa de flag, então `\w` já [considera todas as letras (e dígitos) definidas pelo Unicode](https://ideone.com/hOW7go), no JavaScript a flag `u` [não muda o comportamento do `\w`](https://jsfiddle.net/g0p6nk9h/) (sempre vai ser igual a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` - não lembro se depende do browser), em outras linguagens pode funcionar igual - ou parecido - ao regex101, e por aí vai...

Comment: @LuizFelipe O link do ideone.com que coloquei acima não mostra todos os caracteres, acho que é porque estoura o limite de tempo. Mas aqui dá pra ver todos: https://repl.it/repls/LightheartedOverdueDictionaries

Comment: Sobre o comentário acima: os links anônimos não funcionam mais no repl.it então fiz outra versão em: https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/LightheartedOverdueDictionaries#main.py

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
/^{+({.*?})}+$/
```

Basicamente, ela irá dar *match* em uma string do seguinte modo:

- `^{+` ⇒ Comece com um ou mais caracteres `{`;
- `(` ⇒ Criamos um grupo de captura:

  - `{` ⇒ Tenha um outro caractere `{` (após todos os demais selecionados anteriormente);
  - `.*?` ⇒ Contenha qualquer caractere, até encontrar um `}` (já que estamos utilizando o quantificador *lazy* (`?`).
  - `}` ⇒ Tenha um caractere `}`.
  - `)` ⇒ Finalizamos o grupo de captura.
- `}+$` ⇒ Contenha um ou mais caracteres `}` até o final da string.

Você pode ver funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/kavd87/2).

---

Vale ressaltar que usei o padrão de Expressões Regulares suportadas pelo JavaScript. Então podemos criar um *fiddle*:

```js
const string = '{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{Valor aqui dentro}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}';

const [, group] = string.match(/^{+({.*?})}+$/);

console.log(group);
```

---

Por fim, vale deixar claro que essa expressão regular não verifica se a quantidade de chaves de abertura (`{`) é igual à quantidade de chaves de fechamento `}`.

Comment: Vale comentar que a regex em questão não leva em consideração os { } estarem balanceados ou não (o que não parece ser um problema aqui, só comentando mesmo, tanto que positivei)

Comment: De fato, vou editar a resposta adicionando essa observação...

Comment: @Bacco, só por curiosidade, você sabe se tem como fazer essa determinação da quantidade de caracteres? Eu não consigo pensar em nenhum jeito de fazer ele levar esse balanceamento...

Comment: Se fosse o mesmo caractere podia usar backreference. Com caracteres diferentes não vejo solução prática assim de imediato. Inclusive, se o balanceamento fosse uma necessidade real, nem acho que RegEx seria a ferramenta correta (e não estou sugerindo que seja a melhor opção no caso em questão).

Comment: @Bacco e Luiz, é possível verificar o balanceamento com regex, usando regex recursiva (coloquei uma opção no final da [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/429402/112052)). Mas na minha opinião, está **muito** longe de ser a melhor solução...

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução rápida poderia ser :

```
({[^{}]+})
```

Capturar tudo que se encontra entre `{}` excepto `{` ou `}`.

> Grupei o resultado, talvez você precisara reutilizar os dados capturados.

https://regex101.com/r/DRA2bD/2/