# Regex para pegar tudo em parênteses em determinadas situações

Tags: regex

Preciso criar uma regex para extrair de um código tudo que é passado como parâmetro para as funções, mas só pode ser capturado em determinadas funções. Tenho a regex que pega tudo em parênteses, mas quando aplico o *lookbehind* acaba bugando tudo.

Regex:

```
(?<=Html->script|cell|element|Html->css)([^-]+)[^\(']+(\([^\)]+\))
```

Situações que ela deveria capturar os parâmetros da função:

```
$this->element('element.ctp');
$this->cell('teste.ctp');
$this->Html->script([
    'teste.js'
]);
$this->Html->script([
    'teste.js',
    'teste2.js',
]);
$this->Html->script(['teste.js']);
$this->Html->script('teste.js');
$this->Html->css(['teste.css']);
$this->Html->css('teste.css');
```

Comment: Qual linguagem ou ferramenta/engine de regex vc está usando? É importante colocar, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito, e o que funciona pra uma pode não funcionar pra outra. Ainda mais pra um caso complexo desse (para o qual, já adianto, regex **não** é a melhor solução)

Comment: A regex será construída em typescript e vai ler códigos em PHP. Quero criar um plugin para VS Code

Comment: Nesse caso, vale lembrar que [lookbehind ainda não é suportado por todos os browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility) (no momento, Firefox e Safari não suportam). Acho até que tem algumas libs que fazem o *polyfill*, mas mesmo assim acho que não vale a pena. Ainda acho melhor pesquisar algum parser, por exemplo, esse aqui parece promissor (mas eu não testei): https://github.com/glayzzle/php-parser

Comment: Esse realmente parece ser bem melhor e ainda já expandiu mais o que eu poderia fazer no plugin. Vou testar, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer é um [*parser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), e não uma regex. Pesquise um específico para a linguagem em questão e use-o, dará menos trabalho que uma regex (e mesmo que dê "mais" trabalho, ainda sim compensará, pois regex não é a ferramenta mais adequada para esta tarefa).

Regex pode até funcionar para casos mais simples, mas código fonte de linguagens em geral costuma ser mais complexo e ter várias situações que uma regex não consegue detectar (ou até consegue, mas ela fica tão complicada que não vale a pena).

Por exemplo, para o seu caso, algo que *poderia* funcionar é:

```
(?<=Html->script|cell|element|Html->css)\(([^\)]+)\)
```

Retirei os parênteses do grupo de captura para que ele pegue somente os parâmetros, e removi os outros trechos que não pareciam fazer sentido: `[^-]+` é um ou mais caracteres que não sejam hífen, e `[^\(']+` é um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `(` nem `'`. Ou seja, sua regex exigia que tivesse pelo menos dois caracteres antes do primeiro `(` - o problema não era o *lookbehind* em si, e sim a exigência desses caracteres antes do primeiro `(`.

A regex acima pega tudo que estiver entre os parênteses, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/uEgPaK/1/).

---

Mas como eu já disse, linguagens de programação aceitam expressões mais complexas que isso. E se o seu código tiver algo como:

```php
$this->Html->css(outraFuncaoQueRetornaOcss());
```

A regex só pega o trecho `outraFuncaoQueRetornaOcss(`, deixando o `)` de fora. Isso porque o trecho `[^\)]+` só pega os caracteres que não são `)`, por isso ela para quando encontra um. E aí você teria que usar algo como [regex recursiva](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) para verificar parênteses balanceados (e é tão complicado que não vale a pena - [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/429402/112052) um exemplo - além de muitas linguagens nem terem suporte a este recurso).

E se o trecho estiver comentado? Não está claro qual linguagem é essa (mas tem cara de ser PHP), mas enfim:

```php
// $this->Html->css('teste.css');

/* ou comentário multi-linha
$this->Html->script('teste.js');
$this->Html->css(['teste.css']);
*/
```

A regex não detecta isso, e pega os trechos acima erroneamente, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/uEgPaK/2/) (por outro lado, um *parser* detectaria isso e ignoraria as linhas acima sem problema). Até dá para fazer uma regex que detecte comentários, mas será que vale a pena adicionar [algo desse tipo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114141) a uma expressão que já não está lá muito simples?

E comentários podem ser ainda mais traiçoeiros:

```php
$this->Html->script([
    'teste.js', // algum comentário
    'teste2.js', // outro comentário
]);
```

O parâmetro da função é o array `['teste.js', 'teste2.js']`, mas a regex considera que os comentários fazem parte do mesmo. Boa sorte fazendo uma regex para detectar isso e eliminar corretamente os comentários - talvez seja possível, mas será tão complicado que não valerá a pena (já um *parser* ignoraria os comentários tranquilamente).

Enfim, há situações demais para detectar, e muitas delas não são óbvias de se fazer com regex. No fundo, você teria que escrever um "mini-parser" com regex, que [não é lá uma solução muito inteligente](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5389244) (para fins de aprendizado, talvez valha a pena tentar, mas para uma solução a ser usada em sistemas reais, aí não). Regex é legal (eu gosto bastante), [mas nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: Como eu quero criar um plugin para VS Code acredito que a regex que você me passou já atende, pois o que ela extrair ainda vou tratar no código, mas ainda vou testar mais situações e dar uma estudada sobre Parser. Obrigado!